# jQuery returns only first matched element

Tags: jquery

I am using Chrome console to select all the divs with the class "lockup" from Netflix's page and I only get the first element returned to me.

I believe this would be applicable to all the genre pages of Netflix if you wish to try it on your own. Here is the page html source.

[image: Netflix HTML code on the genre page]

I am attempting to select all the divs with class "lockup" using the following in the chrome console and I only get on result back.

```
$('.lockup')
```

I get the following back:

```
<div class="lockup" data-titleid="80039054" data-trackid="13462986">...</div>
```

Comment: `$('.lockup').length` returns `1`, yes?

Comment: No it does not. It seems like the return element is not an array.

Comment: Yeah, as already suggested in the answer, `$` doesn't point to jQuery then (although even jQuery doesn't return an array, but a jQuery object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the solution would be to use vanilla Javascript querySelectors, `document.querySelectorAll('.lockup')` in this case, however, I found that I could also use `jQuery('.lockup')` as well

**Updated Apr 26th, 2016**

The issue in part because the chrome console does not come with jQuery as $. you can use a browser extension such as jQuerify for Chrome to add jQuery to any page.

Answer (score 4):

*"I am using Chrome console to select all the divs with the class "lockup"..."*

You're assuming that `$` points to jQuery.

In the Chrome console, if jQuery isn't loaded (or `window.$` isn't otherwise used), it'll define a `$` function that returns the first element found (basically like `querySelector`), not a jQuery object.

To get multiple elements, use `document.querySelectorAll(".lockup")`.